# MVC View is being refreshed after button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, model-view-controller, page-refresh

I have a View and it's Controller. The view has the following button (which is repeated multiple times for different variants):

```
        <button type="button" id="@variant.id" onclick="return Select()" style="padding:10px 15px;width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:-10px;">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img width="100" height="100" style="padding:5px" src="/test/@variant.logo" title="@variant.name" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h4>@variant.name</h4>
                        </div>
        </button>
```

This is the function that it accesses:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function Select()
      {        
        alert("test");
        return false;           
      }
   </script>
```

For some reason after the function call, the View is always being refreshed. Do you know what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: You code should work, Is this your complete code?

Comment: Does the button, or child elements, have any other event handlers on it that might be doing a refresh?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you are doing anything to cause it to refresh in that code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maybe use prevent default to stop the event, see also event.stopPropagation().

Here I'm preventing the event, maybe you should use it if your condition is false.

```js
function select(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('test');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="@variant.id" onclick="select(event)" style="padding:10px 15px;width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:-10px;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img width="100" height="100" style="padding:5px" src="/test/@variant.logo" title="@variant.name" />

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h4>@variant.name</h4>
                </div>
</button>
```